# Connecting to a database on a LAN network location

Tags: c#, winforms, oledb, network-drive

I have an application that I want to access a file over a network. I am currently using this connection string.

```
string myconnectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=\\" + PCName + "\\datafolder\\data.mdb";
```

The Pc name is the name of well the computer as seen on the network I get that using:

Dll Netapi32
however while i do get the path exactly as it should be my code adds "C:" to the path instead of "\PCNAME\datafolder\data.mdb"
I have read a lot on this and none of it makes much sense because my code looks exactly as it should except i get that complication.

Comment: I think you are missing an backslash. You have `Data Source=\\PCNAME\\...`, which escaped will be `\PCNAME\...`, but UNC paths should have two leading backslashes: `Data Source=\\\\PCNAME\\...`.

Comment: to avoid "\\" problem. why not use @ before string value asign. `string myconnectionstring = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=\\" + PCName + "\datafolder\data.mdb";`

Comment: I'll try that.. does "@" apply for c# winforms then? i had thought it was for asp.net

Comment: I tried with the "@" however i still got an error "carlpett" yours worked thank you

Comment: @Broken_Code '@' works for C# in general, regardless of whether it is being used in ASP .NET or Winforms etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code line is looking pretty good. Try to add @ before the string or add back slash like this `\\\\" + PCName`

```
string myconnectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=\\\\" + PCName + "\\datafolder\\data.mdb";
```

If still it creates problem then assign that database shared folder as a **Mapped Drive** and use something like this. for example mapped drive is **Z: (\\PCName\ApplicationFolder)**

```
string myconnectionstring = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=Z:\datafolder\data.mdb";
```

also this solution does not working then the problem may be in network pc permission.