# How get current working path to accessdb with c#?

Tags: c#, ms-access

for example, I have a connection string

```
connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; 
              Data Source=D:\WindowsFormsApplication4\bin\Debug\some.mdb");
```

but it works correctly only on my computer. How can I make it work correctly on all computers?

Comment: unclear question , describe more your question

Comment: for example, I have a connectiob string   connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=D:\WindowsFormsApplication4\bin\Debug\some.mdb");
but it works correct, only on my computer, how I can make it working correctly at all computers?

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information

Comment: @AliceBu I Updated my answer

Comment: You shouldn't store the connectionstring information directly inside your code. You put it in the exe.config of your application where any install tool can easily modify it. Use the ConfigurationManager class and its ConnectionString property to retrieve your info. Thousands of examples here and on the wide net.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
string myconnectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=\\\\" + PCName + "\\datafolder\\some.mdb";
```

Specify the `PCNAME` .

If still it creates problem then assign that database shared folder as a Mapped Drive and use something like this. for example mapped drive is Z: (\PCName\ApplicationFolder)

For more Details please refer to the link : [Connecting to a database on a LAN network location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23489980/connecting-to-a-database-on-a-lan-network-location)

Answer (score 0):

The offending code is the following:

```
Data Source=D:\WindowsFormsApplication4\bin\Debug\some.mdb"
```

Basically, you're hardcoding your connection string to a location on your computer. The use of "\bin\Debug" is particularly problematic given that this is *almost certainly* different than what the path will be in your actual production environment.

I'd recommend putting this in a configuration file of some kind if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Always start here.

https://www.connectionstrings.com/

In your case, I think it should be something like this.

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;
```